# What's the difference between Android HAL and Linux UIO?

Tags: android, driver

From my understanding, they are both frameworks for user space device drivers.
Via Android HAL, a vendor does not have to open their driver source code. UIO can achieve same goal.
I do not dig more in code level. Is Android HAL based on UIO. If not, why not?

Comment: I think they are similar because they share similar idea that is to implement majority driver logic in user space. There is already UIO. Why google developer a brand new one?